# How do I properly use javascript axios .get() function to call get_queryset() function in Django viewset?

Tags: reactjs, django, redux, django-rest-framework, axios

I followed a youtube guide to implement a React/Redux frontend that uses javascript axios to make requests to a Django REST framework backend. I've been adding a lot of my own work to it. Here is the original github repository if you think you need it to answer my question, although you shouldn't:
[Link To Github](https://github.com/bradtraversy/lead_manager_react_django)

I have a new method I use to get what I call `eventdefinitions`. Sometimes I want all of the `eventdefinitions` that are in the database, but sometimes I only want some of them. In the original guide, the only way I was taught to get data, was to get all of the data, and so to get all `eventdefinitions`, I would do the following:

In javascript, I use the following method which implements `axios`:

```
// GET EVENT DEFINITIONS
export const getEventDefinitions = () => (dispatch, getState) => {
  axios
    .get("/api/eventdefinitions/", tokenConfig(getState))
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_EVENTDEFINITIONS,
        payload: res.data,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) =>
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status))
    );
};
```

In my `urls.py` file I set up the url_patterns for the `/api/eventdefinitions/` url:

```
from rest_framework import routers
from .api import ... EventDefinitionViewSet, ...

router = routers.DefaultRouter()

...
router.register('api/eventdefinitions', EventDefinitionViewSet, 'eventdefinitions')
...

urlpatterns = router.urls
```

The `EventDefinitionViewSet` in this file comes from the `api.py` file:

```
from .models import ... EventDefinition, ... //not really sure why this is imported, irrelevant
from rest_framework import viewsets, permissions
from .serializers import ... EventDefinitionSerializer, ...

...

class EventDefinitionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticated
    ]

    serializer_class = EventDefinitionSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.request.user.eventdefinitions.all()

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)

...
```

The `EventDefinitionSerializer` is implemented in my `serializers.py` file:

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import ... EventDefinition, ...

class EventDefinitionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = EventDefinition
        fields = '__all__'
```

The last bit of code is the file `models.py` which implements the `EventDefinition` model:

```
class EventDefinition(models.Model):
    event_id = models.SmallIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    event_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    priority = models.SmallIntegerField()
    recurring = models.BooleanField()
    active_for_generation = models.BooleanField()
    owner = models.ForeignKey(
        User, related_name="eventdefinitions", on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

I use React/Redux where I put all of my `eventdefinitions` and the function `getEventDefinitions` into the `props`, and finally, I call the function `getEventDefinitions` in my React function `componentDidMount()`:

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getEventDefinitions();
}
```

I've mentioned all of this to say that this works exactly as intended. When I call `this.props.getEventDefinitions()`, I'm able to put all of the `eventdefinitions` into my component's props. Here comes the part I'm unsure of. How do I select only some of these `eventdefinitions`. I want to be able to either get all of them, get the last one added (largest `event_id`), get the first one added (smallest `event_id`), and get an `eventdefinition` by its `event_id`. I've found a lot of useful information on multiple stackoverflow threads, and I've implemented all of these methods. Strangely, none of these are working, not even getting all of the `eventdefinitions`, even though not much has changed to get this. I changed a few things to try to do this. I'll go in the same order as before.

I changed the `axios` bit by having an argument which can take many values. I call it `event_id`, but really it can have many different values. This code informs me that there is an issue, but it doesn't throw any errors. I know there is an issue because my Redux store doesn't show that the `GET_EVENTDEFINITIONS` action has been called. This means that the `.then` is never triggered, which means that there is never a response. Note that I changed the url so that it has an additional `?event_id=${event_id}`. I learned that the value of `event_id` can be pulled out in the ViewSet if I write the url like this:

```
// GET EVENT DEFINITIONS
export const getEventDefinitions = (event_id) => (dispatch, getState) => {
  axios
    .get(`/api/eventdefinitions?event_id=${event_id}`, tokenConfig(getState))
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_EVENTDEFINITIONS,
        payload: res.data,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) =>
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status))
    );
};
```

In my `urls.py` nothing changes:

```
...
```

The `EventDefinitionViewSet` in this file comes from the `api.py` file changes quite a bit, this is where I am trying to pull out the `event_id` value that I input in the axios javascript bit (two code blocks above). If I had to guess what I'm doing wrong, it's in this file. My reasoning is that since I'm getting no response, it's probably because when I call `.get`, either the `get_queryset` function in this file isn't being called at all, hence no response, or `get_queryset` is being called, but `event_id` does not have the value `'all'`, `'last'`, or `'first'`:

```
from .models import ... EventDefinition, ... //not really sure why this is imported, irrelevant
from rest_framework import viewsets, permissions
from .serializers import ... EventDefinitionSerializer, ...

...

class EventDefinitionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    permission_classes = [
        permissions.IsAuthenticated
    ]

    serializer_class = EventDefinitionSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):

        event_id = self.request.GET.get("event_id")

        if event_id == 'all':
            return self.request.user.eventdefinitions.all()
        elif event_id == 'last':
            return [self.request.user.eventdefinitions.order_by("-event_id")[0]]
        elif event_id == 'first':
            return [self.request.user.eventdefinitions.order_by("event_id")[0]]
        else:
            return [self.request.user.eventdefinitions.get(pk=event_id)]

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        return serializer.save(owner=self.request.user)

...
```

The `EventDefinitionSerializer` doesn't change:

```
...
```

The `models.py` file doesn't change:

```
...
```

Finally, I call the `getEventDefinitions` function in my React `componentDidMount` lifecycle function. This could also be an issue, but I don't think so because I've tried many things, and at first I was getting lots of https errors, but when I tried this, they went away (of course there could still be an issue, but this is the best I've been able to do):

```
componentDidMount() {
    this.props.getEventDefinitions.bind(this, 'all');
}
```

I should mention that when `getEventDefinitions()` is called, it calls a reducer function that pretty much just adds the values to the state, but since I know the `.then` function isn't being called, there is no reason to know about how this is handled. So finally, what is the issue with how I changed my files to compensate for the added input value? Is it my ViewSet? Or maybe it's an issue with something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing something like this for the get_queryset function:

```
def get_queryset(self):

    queryset = EventDefinition.objects.all()

    event_filter = self.request.GET.get("event_filter", None)

    if event_filter == 'last':
        ordered_queryset = queryset.order_by("-event_id")
        if ordered_queryset.count() == 0:
            return []
        else:
            return [ordered_queryset.first()]

    if event_filter == 'first':
        ordered_queryset = queryset.order_by("event_id")
        if ordered_queryset.count() == 0:
            return []
        else:
            return [ordered_queryset.first()]

    return queryset
```

And I did this for the axios part:

```
// GET EVENT DEFINITIONS
export const getEventDefinitions = (event_id) => (dispatch, getState) => {

  const getString = typeof(event_id) === "number" ?
    `/api/eventdefinitions/${event_id}/` :
    (typeof(event_id) === "string" ?
      `/api/eventdefinitions?event_filter=${event_id}` :
      "/api/eventdefinitions/")

  axios
    .get(getString, tokenConfig(getState))
    .then((res) => {
      dispatch({
        type: GET_EVENTDEFINITIONS,
        payload: res.data,
      });
    })
    .catch((err) =>
      dispatch(returnErrors(err.response.data, err.response.status))
    );
};
```

Comment: Credits to pplonski's answer for helping me figure this out.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is [DRF filtering](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/).

Maybe you should rename your filter to `event_filter`.

Example:

```py
    def get_queryset(self):

        queryset = EventDefinition.objects.all()

        event_filter = self.request.query_params.get('event_filter', None)

        if event_filter == 'last':
            return [queryset.order_by("-event_id")[0]]
        if event_filter == 'first':
            return [queryset.order_by("event_id")[0]]

        return queryset
```

URLs:

- to get all `/api/eventdefinitions`
- to get selected by event_id (primary key) `/api/eventdefinitions/1` <- the `1` is your primary key
- to get last: `/api/eventdefinitions/?event_filter=last`
- to get first: `/api/eventdefinitions/?event_filter=first`

BTW, I'm working now on series of [tutorials on how to build SaaS application from scratch with Django and React](https://saasitive.com/django-react/boilerplate/). You may find it interesting.